# Calling a method in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have ThreadPoolExecutor and BlockingQueue in the class:

```
class Test {
private final SomeSharedData sharedField;

private OkHttpClient httpClient;
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
private BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue;

public void doWork(){ 
  ...
}

}
```

And in this class I have method `doWork()` that is reading from this queue in a `while(true)` loop. It is doing some work with HTTP and `sharedField`. Is it okay if I will add in the executor multiple callings of this method? Like this:

```
executor.execute(this::doWork);
executor.execute(this::doWork);
```

Is it normal way to use it like this, I'm concerned because the threads will be using one method of the same object, or should I write a class that will implement runnable with `doWork()` logic (normal way)? I know, there might be a problem with synchronization, because threads will be working with the fields of this object, but I will synchronize the fields I need when I'm using them, if I do it, is it normal to use it like this or there might be another problems?

Comment: You should only synchronize if you actually need to (e.g. modifying state), synchronizing just because you're doing something multi-threaded is the wrong approach. In any case, this is not generally answerable without a [mre] (and then answers would only apply to that example, so might not be applicable).

Comment: If you synchronize where needed, your approach should work fine. Did you run tests?

Comment: Mark, I think I gave enough info to understand the question, because it's not about the code so there's no need to reproduce it, it's question about how it's normal in Java

Comment: Datz, yeah, tests are working but I wanted to know if it's okay or I need to use something else, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be cautious

Unfortunately, with concurrent processing, tests might succeed many times but then randomly fail because of a different winner in race conditions, so I'd be cautious in trusting them (unless you write very good concurrency tests). Also, when talking about synchronization, it is pretty hard to be sure it's right without getting down to the code and knowing what's expected and what state changes are valid.

Unless `SomeSharedData` is **read-only** after you pass it to this `Test` , I'd be very careful..

You say you'll "synchronize the fields I need when I'm using them" but that might not be enough, just because your calls wait in line to read/write the fields doesn't mean you've synchronized correctly. If something changes a field of `SomeSharedData` while a `doWork()` thread is running then it could read the field as one value at one moment then another value the next, which could potentially break some things..

*Couldn't fit this in a comment.*

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think the same problems would appear if I was using runnable instead, my question was more about "is it okay practice to do like this", but thanks for the note

Comment: @Arzybek Well, technically, you **are** using a `Runnable`, so yes the same problems would appear. The method you're calling is `Executor.execute(Runnable)` you're just using the fact that `Runnable` is a `@FunctionalInterface` so you can shortcut the declaration using a method reference (`this::doWork`) to make it more clear/less verbose. It's ok practice to do what you're doing, so long as you're careful, but *best practice* (in general..) is to use immutable objects in concurrent processing wherever possible.